# Software to animate videos with video templates

Tags: windows, video, animation

I have been looking for software which:

- Can be used to create animations;
- Contains video animations as templates;
- Is similar to, and with templates like, [goanimate.com](http://goanimate.com) [this one was web based].

Software requirements :

- Can be a shareware/freeware but watermarking should not be allowed;
- Windows platform will be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Model your software requirements based on Adobe's Creative Suite and thereafter begin trialling the leading free alternatives.

For special effects and post-production video editing, try [Wax](http://www.debugmode.com/wax/) as a replacement for Adobe After Effects (it's old but robust). [Blender](http://www.blender.org/), though primarily for 3D, makes standard special effect creation possible.

For standard video editing, try [Da Vinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) as a replacement for Adobe Premiere. The free lite version, though limited, will get the job done.

For vector-based ("cartoonish") animation, whereby you draw your own material rather than importing footage, use [Apache Flex](http://flex.apache.org/) as a replacement for Adobe Flash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Adobe Flash** but it is paid version, to create animation. And download free video template as per your need as so many templates are available. To download **Adobe Flash Professional CC** software see this link
 http://www.adobe.com/in/products/flash.html

There is an **[alternative to Adobe Flash](http://www.opensourcealternative.org/alternatives/graphic-editors/open-source-alternative-to-flash-professional/)** which is open source. Select the appropriate which fulfill your requirement.